# Перевод .db в .ib.

Tags: delphi, компоненты, база-данных

Есть база данных с расширением .ib, с неизвестной структурой, и требуется туда внести данные из парадоксовских таблиц. В Delphi7 компоненты для работы с .gdb. Может кто нибудь может посоветовать что-то?

Answer (score 1):

Если задача просто внести разово данные, то используйте InterBase Expert, если задача написать ПО для работы с этой базой постоянно, то в Delphi7, как и в последующих версиях есть стандартные компоненты для работы с InterBase/FireBird на вкладке Interbase. Можно обойтись ими, а можно установить дополнительный пакет компонентов FIBPlus.

Answer (score 0):

Ib - это вроде как формат БД InterBase. А им по умолчанию комплектуются Delphi. Более того - по идее никаких доп. компонентов ставить не надо. Достаточно, чтобы в системе стоял драйвер ODBC для соответствующего типа БД и тогда можно будет открыть базу стандартными компонентами. Касательно структуры БД - она вообще-то должна содержаться в файле базы данных, иначе как же эту БД модифицировать!?

P.S. а paradox должен легко открываться через bde, которым дельфи снабжены.....